# CrossProduct and DotProduct - Expand these equations

Tags: triangulation, dot-product, cross-product

I'm trying to use a formulae from http://www.blackpawn.com/texts/pointinpoly/default.html the upper of the two options.  (I have already used the lower).

I just can not seem to wrap my head around the CrossProduct(b-a, p1-a) etc.  Could someone Please expand these for me.  They are below.

```
function SameSide(p1,p2, a,b)
    cp1 = CrossProduct(b-a, p1-a)
    cp2 = CrossProduct(b-a, p2-a)
    if DotProduct(cp1, cp2) >= 0 then return true
    else return false
```

as I understand it they should come out to this.

```
##  Using the following as p=x,z, a=x,z, b=x,z, c=x,z
##  p=4,1 a=2,0 b=4,3 c=0,4
function SameSide(px, pz, ax, az, bx, bz, cx, cz){
    cp1x=(cx-bx*px-bx)
    cp1z=(cz-bz*pz-bz)
    cp2x=(cx-bx*ax-bx)
    cp2z=(cz-bz*az-bz)
    DotProd=(cp1x*cp2x+cp1z*cp2z)
}
```

But when trying this in Excel I get wrong answers again.

Please help! 8-|

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `DotProduct` computation is correct. However, the cross product of 2 vectors `v` and `w` is :

```
cpx = vy*wz - vz*wy
cpy = vz*wx - vx*wz
cpz = vx*wy - vy*wx
```

where in your case, `vx = bx-ax` vy = `by-ay` and `vz=bz-az`, and wx=`p1x-ax` (or respectively `p2x-ax`) and similarly for `y` and `z`.